# i upload my app in playstore,when i search not show my app

Tags: android

this is my app link
[image: app name]

[app link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sl.newsinone)

i give the app name News in one
search not found my app
this name type search not found my app.
when i search newsinone that time only show the my apps.. 
what problem?
how can i do.how to solve this problem

Comment: [My app is not showing on Play Store when I search it by its name?](https://www.quora.com/My-app-is-not-showing-on-Play-Store-when-I-search-it-by-its-name)

Answer (score 0):

If you just uploaded the app now, it'll take a few hours before it appears live on the play store, what you may be seeing from the developer console could just be a preview.
If you're sure the app has gone live on the store, then be patient with the search because there are so many apps with the name News alongside so yours is probably down the list. If this is the case I'll advice you stick to sharing your app link first, so you'll gain some traction and downloads to move up the list or consider changing the app display name to something less generic like 'News'

Comment: i uploaded yesterday,,

Comment: Then see the 2nd part of my comment about the name